# I deployed my react app on firebase and I can access only route "/" from outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed my react app on firebase and I can access only route "/" from outside.
For better understanding. This is my url: https://clone-2017c.web.app/

If I try to go on https://clone-2017c.web.app/orders, it will return me 404 page from Firebase.
But this page exist, it works on localhost and on deployed app to if I access the page from the header link. It send me to the same link, but this time will return my react component.

Do someone know what should I do? It is possible to make it work on Firebase?
I have confirmation email, so I'll need to fix it.
Thank you!

Comment: are you rendering the app in the server or just in the client. (is it isomorphoc, hate that term) and can you link to other pages once you are from the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution, then a comment

since you have not specified otherwise, firebase will look for a file with the name of the route.
in your firebase.json add this block:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
      {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
      }
  ]
}
```

inside the 'hosting' directive.
this tells firebase to send all requests to index.html, where your router will solve the path

now the comment:
if possible, avoid using 'real' URL routing on frontend, use #route instead, since URLs are supposed to identify a specific resource, you won't be linking to any specific resource. this would also solve your problem.

Comment: It works if I use #route, but I used Heroku in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your Routes infrastructure works correctly and check your firebase deploying configurations